# Python - Convert an array of UTM coordinates to Geo

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following method for converting coordinates:

```
def UTM_to_Geo(x, y):
...
return [x,y]
```

And I have an array of x's and y's (2d array) called `locations`.
Can I invoke the method on each of the items in the array with `map`?

Comment: You can use [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#small-functions-and-the-lambda-expression) to pass argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
geos=list(map(lambda l: UTM_toGeo(l[0], l[1]), locations))
```

Comment: The question is tagged python-2.7 where `map()` already returns a list and it doesn't make sense to copy all the elements into yet another list.